# Enabling simultaneous turns in Heroes of Might and Magic 3 HotA

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

I would love to be able to play this game in single player and simultaneous turns! :D Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

### There is little reason to do this

While [simultaneous turns](https://sites.google.com/site/heroes3hd/eng/simultaneous-turns-st) (STs) are possible in HotA, a mod for HoMM 3, the limitations placed upon that mechanic make it totally irrelevant for playing against a computer opponent. Basically, if you interact with each other or the same object, STs stop, and Blue players' turn is canceled and has to be replayed. With or without STs, there is not supposed to be any change in actual game results: you only save time.

Also, there isn't much benefit to this. When human players take large amounts of time for each of their turns, waiting for your opponent can be tedious, boring, and frustrating.This is why you need STs in the first place. After you meet for the first time and STs stop, the game is likely to be over soon, so you avoid most of the wait.

At the same time, a computer opponent doesn't take anywhere as long as a human to finish their turn. This is why you don't *need* STs against a computer opponent in the first place, as it would result in practically no changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Heroes of Might and Magic has always been [turn-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn-based_strategy), which is very distinctive from [real-time strategy games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_strategy) like the Warcraft and Starcraft series. You can't expect the software to support such a change, though with some modifications it could probably work from a game rules perspective.

Comment: Thank you, the reason for asking is in horn of the abyss you can play simultaneously in multiplayer. I had hoped I might be able to enable it for single player

Comment: I am sorry, but this answer really doesn't take into account that the game is modded, [simultaneous turns](https://sites.google.com/site/heroes3hd/eng/description/hd_plus/sim-turn) having been added as a mechanic. OP is asking whether or not they are possible in single-player games as they are possible in multiplayer.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Ah, I didn't know about this particular mod. I only know the official games...